# Package html2text is obsolete!

Tags: package

I am getting this message during startup of my Emacs, recently (since the update to Emacs 26?). I could not track down where is package is loaded and did not find anything related to this message in the web. It is not really a problem but I would like to know why my Emacs loads an obsolete package.

Comment: It may be surprising, but it's far from unusual to use packages that didn't get the memo yet. Figuring this out is something you'll have to do yourself, by testing whether you get the same message with `emacs -q` / `emacs -Q`, then bisecting towards the offending part of your init / site file.

Comment: I was hoping someone already did this ;-) Then I will see, when I find the time and track down the „problem“.

Comment: *Sorry for posting this as an answer, but I am not allowed to post comments yet and this post was so relevant that asking a new question didn't feel any better than this and it might have never attracted the attention of Martin Buchmann...* From Martin Buchmann's comments: > It was indeed an old version of mu4e. Making sure that the recent version is loaded everything is fine @Martin Buchmann: may I ask you how you did this? I am having the exact same issue, but it seems that I am using the most recent version of mu/mu4e (from May 31 as shown [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community

Comment: @prosoitos I am using `macports` on macOS and there is a mu-devel port which works for me. I not sure which package you could use on your system. But you could a) wait until your system is updated or b) try to get the most recent commit using `git`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the top of your .emacs, you should get a backtrace when it loads:

```el
(defun debug-on-load-obsolete (filename)
  (when (equal (car (last (split-string filename "[/\\]") 2))
               "obsolete")
    (debug)))
(add-to-list 'after-load-functions #'debug-on-load-obsolete)
```

Comment: That helped a lot! I could track down the loading to mu4e and will investigate it further.

Comment: It was indeed an old version of mu4e. Making sure that the recent version is loaded everything is fine.

Comment: This causes my emacs-daemon to collaps

Comment: @alper oh, I guess `debug` wouldn't run in daemon mode. Maybe replacing the `(debug)` call with `(backtrace)` would work?

Comment: The error I was getting: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/47792d4e5316a0b530c9ef2be1060aca

Comment: @alper well that's enough to figure out where the obsolete message is coming from: the `findr` package is loading the obsolete `cl` package (it should switch to `cl-lib`).